# analytic continuation of Krassner's analytic element on punctured disk

Tags: p-adic, analytic-continuation

Let
$$
E=\{x\in\mathbb Q_p\mid |x|_p\le p^{-2}\}\setminus\left\{p^n\mid n\in\mathbb N,n\ge2\right\}
$$ and $g$ be an analytic element (in Krassner's sense) of
$$
F=\{x\in\mathbb Q_p\mid |x|_p<1\}\setminus\left\{p^n\mid n\in\mathbb N\right\}.
$$
Suppose that for all $x\in E$, $g(x)=0$. Can one assert that $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in F$? Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - don't $1/p^n$ have $p$-adic norms $p^n$? Are the sets supposed to be defined some other way?

Comment: Yes, it was a bad copy paste. Sorry for the trouble. I modified the post.